Simplifying quantum computing expression
I am working through Lecture Notes by Ronald Wolf: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1907.09415
I am trying to solve exercise 1.5 (page 11 in the pdf) which goes like the following:
Simplify the following: $(\langle0|\otimes I)(\alpha_{00}|00\rangle + \alpha_{01}|01\rangle + \alpha_{10}|10\rangle + \alpha_{11}|11\rangle)$.
I know how to solve this problem using classical linear algebra. I can calculate a simplified expression using that method. But I am wondering if there is a smart way to abuse the Dirac notation to get to the result possibly in a smarter way?
My current process was the following:
The identity matrix can be written as a sum of ket-bras:
$$
(\langle0|\otimes(|0\times0|+|1\times1|))(\alpha_{00}|00\rangle + \alpha_{01}|01\rangle + \alpha_{10}|10\rangle + \alpha_{11}|11\rangle)
$$
Now, since they are ket-bras I can rewrite to the following:
$$
(\langle 0|0\rangle\langle0|+\langle0|1\rangle\langle1|)(\alpha_{00}|00\rangle + \alpha_{01}|01\rangle + \alpha_{10}|10\rangle + \alpha_{11}|11\rangle)
$$
Since the vectors are of the computational basis, the inner product is 0 if they are not the same, and 1 if they are. Thus I would get the following:
$$
(1\langle0|+0\langle1|)(\alpha_{00}|00\rangle + \alpha_{01}|01\rangle + \alpha_{10}|10\rangle + \alpha_{11}|11\rangle)
$$
But, I know realize there is something wrong in here since the dimensions does not fit anymore. My question is, am I anywhere on the right track or is there no way to accomplish what I am trying to do using the notation?

The expansion of the identity into $|0\rangle\langle0|+|1\rangle\langle 1|$ is fine. It is the step after that which is incorrect, e.g.,
$$
\langle 0|\otimes|0\rangle\langle0|=|0\rangle\langle00|\color{red}{\neq}\langle 0|=\langle0|0\rangle\langle0|\,.
$$
As you noticed this already cannot be true because the dimensions of these objects are entirely different.
The mathematical property we need to resolve this issue is the "mixed-product property" $AC\otimes BD=(A\otimes B)(C\otimes D)$ of the tensor product. At first glance our problem seems to not fit, until we realize that $\langle 0|=1\cdot\langle 0|$—with $1$ interpreted as a $1\times 1$-dimensional matrix. More generally, it for all $x,y,z$ holds that
$$
\langle x|\otimes|y\rangle\langle z|=1\cdot\langle x|\otimes|y\rangle\langle z|=(1\otimes|y\rangle)(\langle x|\otimes\langle z|)=|y\rangle(\langle x|\otimes\langle z|)\,,
$$
or $|y\rangle\langle xz|$ for short. In the second step we used that the Kronecker product with a number is just standard multiplication so we're just left with $|y\rangle$ there.
As an aside, you can also use the mixed-product property to compute the expression in question directly:
$$
(\langle x|\otimes I)|yz\rangle=(\langle x|\otimes I)(|y\rangle\otimes |z\rangle)=\langle x|y\rangle\otimes I|z\rangle=\langle x|y\rangle\otimes|z\rangle=\langle x|y\rangle\,|z\rangle
$$

So, working a bit with your suggestion. I do manage to get the first part of the expression to be $$ |0\rangle\langle00| + |1\rangle\langle01|$$. But, this does still not seem correct, as I will then get the wrong constant, I believe I should get the final state $\alpha_{00}|0\rangle + \alpha_{10}|1\rangle$, but by using the inner product, it would instead take the constant $\alpha_{01}$. Did I do something wrong somewhere?
I really must admit that trick with treating 1 as a 1 x 1 matrix is really interesting and I would have never guessed that! So thank you

The final expression is indeed $\alpha_{00}|0\rangle+\alpha_{01}|1\rangle$ so you did everything correctly! Intuitively, the reason why the $\alpha_{10}|10\rangle$ term cannot enter the final state is because its first qubit is $|1\rangle$, meaning it has to cancel when multiplying it by $\langle 0|$ (see also the edit to my answer)

But, if I am to calculate the left matrix using linear algebra I get:
$$\begin{pmatrix}1&0&0&0\0&0&1&0\end{pmatrix}$$
Which then, when multiplied on the state gives $\alpha_{00}|0\rangle + \alpha_{10}|1\rangle$ as far as I calculate. I am not sure if I made a mistake, but I just don't  feel like I did.

This is where your mistake lies then. The Kronecker product is defined as $$A\otimes B=\begin{pmatrix}A_{11}B&\ldots&A_{1n}B\\vdots&\ddots&\vdots\A_{m1}B&\cdots&A_{mn}B\end{pmatrix}.$$ Hence $$\langle 0|\otimes{\bf1}=\begin{pmatrix}1&0\end{pmatrix}\otimes\begin{pmatrix}1&0\0&1\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}1\cdot\begin{pmatrix}1&0\0&1\end{pmatrix}&0\cdot\begin{pmatrix}1&0\0&1\end{pmatrix}\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}1&0&0&0\0&1&0&0\end{pmatrix}$$

Ahh, It seems in this calculation I accidentally did it the other way around! Now it makes sense why I couldn't get the results to match ‍♂️Thank you so much for the clarifications and help! :D
